# Ecom Express API Integration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to integrate Ecom Express APIs in my project.
When I use postman to fetch AWB Number then it is giving me the JSON output as follows:

[image]

When I am writing the code on my page then I am unable to get response.

```
<form id="insForm" name="insForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text"id="username" name="username" value="ecomexpress" />
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$" />
<input type="text" id="count" name="count" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="cod" />
</form>

function getAWBNo() {
        var formData = new FormData($('#insForm')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://staging.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            contentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

I am using Razor v3.

Comment: What response you are getting?

Comment: Hello, I am getting the same problem, I tried it with c# server side code also using httpclient but its not working. Did you solve this problem?If yes, Please post answer. Thanks

Comment: hi, what api you used to get status updates of shipments ?

Comment: @ankitsharma hi, what api you used to get status updates of shipments ?

Comment: Hey folks, I'm trying to figure out where the API docs are for EcomExpress as we need to create an integration as well. Some help, please? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You All. I have solved my problem by using Rest API available in NuGet Packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<JsonResult> FetchAWB()
    {
        var options = new RestClientOptions("https://clbeta.ecomexpress.in")
        {
            MaxTimeout = -1,
        };
        var client = new RestClient(options);
        var request = new RestRequest("https://api.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic QU5NT0xDT1VSSUVSU0VSVklDRVMyMTE2NjM6N1ZFaFpHcU11OA==");
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        request.AddParameter("username", "******************");
        request.AddParameter("password", "*********");
        request.AddParameter("count", "1");
        request.AddParameter("type", "PPD");
        RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
       if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode==true)
        {
            FetchAWBModel rcat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FetchAWBModel>(response.Content);
            var pm = rcat.awb;

            return Json(rcat.awb);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(response.Content);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is C# method to fetch_awb.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).